# Show new column in Yii2 Grid, based on difference of dates stored in different records

Tags: yii2

I am having a table called **postings**, which contain the postings of a personnel, identified by the field **cpf** at various places at different dates. Similar to the one shown in the image below.

[image]

Now, in the index view of the Model, I would like show a new column, which calculates the number of days a person was posted at a particular place. For example, the person 39584 was posted at JORHAT for 5322 days (1998-05-29 - 1983-11-02 = 5322). The same person is being posted at IRS for 4259 days (difference of today's date and 2009-05-15).

I am new to Yii2 and need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is a `php` solution OK for you or does it need to be implemented directly in the database? With the `php` solution your index page would be executing a lot more queries.

Comment: Any solution is most helpful and welcomed Raul. Thanks for commenting. I can implement a normal PHP solution for this, however, I am confused to implement this in Yii2, I mean, how to pass that data for each row returned from database, when I am using Yii2's gridview for viewing the index page.